# ExtJS4 DragDrop Proxy positioning

Tags: javascript, extjs4

In ExtJS 4, by default, the dragdrop proxy is displayed to the right bottom position of the mouse position during drag operation. Let say I click into the center of my target and move my mouse by 1 px. I would like the proxy to itself over the original element, shifted by 1 px.

Basically, I need proxy to behave like the example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable. In this example the proxy is over the original element and then moves around when the mouse is dragged.

How can I achieve this?

Here is sample code illustrating the problem when dragging a custom widget.

Ext.onReady(function(){

```
    var hewgt = Ext.define('Demo.widget.Complex', {
                    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
                    alias: 'widget.complex',
                    frameHeader: false,
                    draggable: false, 
                    layout: 'table',
                    initComponent: function() {
                            this.callParent(arguments);
                            var txtFld;
                            this.superclass.add.call(this, txtFld = new Ext.form.field.Text({fieldLabel:'test'}));
                            this.superclass.add.call(this, new Ext.button.Button({text:'Save'}));                              
                    }
    });

    Ext.define('Demo.dd.DragSource', {
                    extend: 'Ext.dd.DragSource',
                    b4MouseDown: function(e) {
            this.diffX = e.getX() - this.el.getX();
            this.diffY = e.getY() - this.el.getY();
                            this.superclass.setDelta.call(this, 0, 0);
                    },
                    getTargetCoord: function(iPageX, iPageY) {
                            return {x: iPageX - this.diffX, y: iPageY - this.diffY};
                    }
    });

    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    layout: 'absolute',
                    title: 'Navigation'
    });

    var vp = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [panel]
    });

    var img = Ext.create('Demo.widget.Complex', { width: 400, height:100, x:20, y:20 });
    panel.add(img);
    new Demo.dd.DragSource(img.getEl());

    img = Ext.create('Demo.widget.Complex', { width: 400, height:100, x:20, y:150 });
    panel.add(img);
    new Demo.dd.DragSource(img.getEl());
```

});

I am new to Ext JS.
Please let me know how can the dragged proxy be positioned correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I found method alignElWithMouse(). Do I need to override this method? Thanks